# dynamic pivot by considering maximum date in oracle sql

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, plsqldeveloper

I have the following table which gets dynamically updated each month

Let's say at end of June, the table is shown below:
[image]

I want to pivot it as follows, Also I'm trying it by converting the Month_Year which is currently string as date and proceeding, below is the expected output

[image]

Similarly at the end of July the input data would be changed as below:
[image]

for which the output I need is shown below:
[image]

I have already tried the below code:

select * from table A
pivot sum(Sales)for to_date(concat(Month_Year,'01'),'YYYYMMDD')
in ((select MAX(to_date(concat(Month_Year,'01'),'YYYYMMDD')) from tabe A),
(select ADD_MONTHS(MAX(to_date(concat(Month_Year,'01'),'YYYYMMDD')),-1) from tabe A),
(select ADD_MONTHS(MAX(to_date(concat(Month_Year,'01'),'YYYYMMDD')),-2) from tabe A),
....so on
)

but i'm getting an error "missing expression"

I have also tried Pivot XML as well, but unable to succeed.

Am I going wrong in Pivot? Also if pivot cannot be applied to such scenario, can you suggest any other way to achieve the expected output?

Comment: If you want to generate columns dynamically based on the maximum date in the table, then you need dynamic SQL, which is a complicated beast. How about generating 12 columns everytime (one per month), with some of the columns having null values if ther date was not reached yet?

Comment: **Tip of the day**: 1. Format your code.  And when asking a question highlight it and clink the {} icon, or CTRL+K. 2. DO NOT post images. See [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) why. 3. Do as @GMB suggests. When GMB says "dynamic SQL is complicated" he is way under stating what you need here. Let your presentation layer truncate the unwanted null months. After all that is why it is called Presentation.